# uikit modal.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit, getuikit

i just learning on web dev, i dont understand javascript yet,,

now i'm make some school project using uikit,,

i try to make modal crud using uikit and jquery,, i try to find form inside modal, but cant use .find()

here the modal html code

```
<div id="modal" uk-modal>
    <form class="uk-form-horizontal">

    </form>
</div>
```

and here the javascript

```
$('#modal').find('form'); //will work

var modal = UIkit.modal('#modal'
    , {bgClose: false, escClose: false}
); //make a modal
modal.find('form'); //will not work, but i must use this, can i?
```

reference [uikit official documentation about modal](https://getuikit.com/docs/modal)

Comment: aw, man,, :( ,,

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
modal.find('form');
```

which is incorrect syntax. Instead, you should try

```
jQuery(modal).find('form');
```